# globalization not working in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, localization, internationalization, globalization

I am trying to implement Globalization in my application but for some reason its not working

Please find the code below

**Default.aspx**

```
<%@ Page Title="Home Page" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Site.master" AutoEventWireup="true"
    CodeFile="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="_Default" %>

<asp:Content ID="HeaderContent" runat="server" ContentPlaceHolderID="HeadContent">
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="BodyContent" runat="server" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent">
    <asp:Button ID="button1" meta:resourceKey="button1" runat="server" Text="" />
</asp:Content>
```

**Default.aspx.cs**

```
 protected override void InitializeCulture()
    {
        Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture =
           CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("en");
        Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = new
            CultureInfo("en-US");

            base.InitializeCulture();
    }
```

name of my resource file is Default.aspx.en-us.resx in "App_LocalResources" folder
it carries only one key
key-->button1.Text
value--> Save

Please advice

Comment: i m getting "The resource class for this page was not found.  Please check if the resource file exists and try again." error

Answer (score 0):

I followed your instructions and got the same results as you, except for the error.  The problem I found was that unless there is a default resource file then the language specific one does not work for some reason.

So I made a copy of the default.aspx.en-us.resx, and named it default.aspx.resx in the same directory, and then made sure that the default.aspx.en-us.resx had a different value than the default and it worked.